# Hibernate generating too many outer joins on my entity relations

Tags: hibernate

I have a couple of entities that share one to many and many to one relationship, i will display below, the issue im having is that i have made a simple native query which works, but doing integration tests with h2 db, i call this query and i get syntax error and seeing how long the query that is generated by hibernate. could anyone please point me to what is exactly wrong ?

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
public class FinancingOffer extends BaseEntity {

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "person_id")
    private Person person;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "financing_price_list_mod_ver_id")
    private FinancingPriceListModVer financingPriceListModVer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "financing_offer_status_id")
    private FinancingOfferStatus financingOfferStatus;

    private String name;
```

// some simple int variables ommited for brevity

}

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class FinancingPriceListModVer extends BaseEntity {

    @OneToOne
    private ModVer modVer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "financing_price_list_id")
    private FinancingPriceList financingPriceList;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "financing_price_list_dnpmt_id")
    private FinancingPriceListDnpmt financingPriceListDnpmt;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "financing_price_list_millage_id")
    private FinancingPriceListMillage financingPriceListMillage;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "financing_price_list_periods_id")
    private FinancingPriceListPeriods financingPriceListPeriods;

    private Integer installment;

}


@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class FinancingOfferStatus extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
    private String description;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "financingOfferStatus")
    private List<FinancingOffer> financingOffers;

}
```

and my repository is

```
@Repository
public interface FinancingOfferRepository extends JpaRepository<FinancingOffer, Long> {

    @Query(value = "select * from financing_offer fo left join financing_price_list_mod_ver fp on fo.financing_price_list_mod_ver_id  = fp.id \n" +
            "where fo.person_id  = ?1 and fp.mod_ver_id = ?2", nativeQuery = true)
    List<FinancingOffer> findByFinancingOfferIfExistByPersonIdAndModVer(Long personId, Long modVerId);

}
```

Now this query works when running the application but today im writing IT tests

and i tried to execute a test which uses this query inside and i get
this and an error message could not prepare statement

```
select financingp0_.id as id1_36_0_, financingp0_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_36_0_, financingp0_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_36_0_, financingp0_.financing_price_list_id as financin5_36_0_, financingp0_.financing_price_list_dnpmt_id as financin6_36_0_, financingp0_.financing_price_list_millage_id as financin7_36_0_, financingp0_.financing_price_list_periods_id as financin8_36_0_, financingp0_.installment as installm4_36_0_, financingp0_.mod_ver_id as mod_ver_9_36_0_, financingp1_.id as id1_33_1_, financingp1_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_33_1_, financingp1_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_33_1_, financingp1_.active as active4_33_1_, financingp1_.archived as archived5_33_1_, financingp1_.description as descript6_33_1_, financingp1_.downpayment_cnt as downpaym7_33_1_, financingp1_.financing_supplier_id as financi11_33_1_, financingp1_.millage_cnt as millage_8_33_1_, financingp1_.name as name9_33_1_, financingp1_.periods_cnt as periods10_33_1_, financings2_.id as id1_40_2_, financings2_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_40_2_, financings2_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_40_2_, financings2_.description as descript4_40_2_, financings2_.name as name5_40_2_, financingp3_.id as id1_34_3_, financingp3_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_34_3_, financingp3_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_34_3_, financingp3_.downpayment_amt as downpaym4_34_3_, financingp3_.downpayment_percent as downpaym5_34_3_, financingp3_.financing_price_list_id as financin6_34_3_, financingp4_.id as id1_33_4_, financingp4_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_33_4_, financingp4_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_33_4_, financingp4_.active as active4_33_4_, financingp4_.archived as archived5_33_4_, financingp4_.description as descript6_33_4_, financingp4_.downpayment_cnt as downpaym7_33_4_, financingp4_.financing_supplier_id as financi11_33_4_, financingp4_.millage_cnt as millage_8_33_4_, financingp4_.name as name9_33_4_, financingp4_.periods_cnt as periods10_33_4_, financingp5_.id as id1_35_5_, financingp5_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_35_5_, financingp5_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_35_5_, financingp5_.financing_price_list_id as financin5_35_5_, financingp5_.millage_limit as millage_4_35_5_, financingp6_.id as id1_33_6_, financingp6_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_33_6_, financingp6_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_33_6_, financingp6_.active as active4_33_6_, financingp6_.archived as archived5_33_6_, financingp6_.description as descript6_33_6_, financingp6_.downpayment_cnt as downpaym7_33_6_, financingp6_.financing_supplier_id as financi11_33_6_, financingp6_.millage_cnt as millage_8_33_6_, financingp6_.name as name9_33_6_, financingp6_.periods_cnt as periods10_33_6_, financingp7_.id as id1_37_7_, financingp7_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_37_7_, financingp7_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_37_7_, financingp7_.financing_price_list_id as financin5_37_7_, financingp7_.period as period4_37_7_, financingp8_.id as id1_33_8_, financingp8_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_33_8_, financingp8_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_33_8_, financingp8_.active as active4_33_8_, financingp8_.archived as archived5_33_8_, financingp8_.description as descript6_33_8_, financingp8_.downpayment_cnt as downpaym7_33_8_, financingp8_.financing_supplier_id as financi11_33_8_, financingp8_.millage_cnt as millage_8_33_8_, financingp8_.name as name9_33_8_, financingp8_.periods_cnt as periods10_33_8_, modver9_.id as id1_47_9_, modver9_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_47_9_, modver9_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_47_9_, modver9_.description1 as descript4_47_9_, modver9_.description2 as descript5_47_9_, modver9_.status_id as status_i6_47_9_, modver9_.vehicle_class_id as vehicle_7_47_9_, modverstat10_.id as id1_50_10_, modverstat10_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_50_10_, modverstat10_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_50_10_, modverstat10_.name as name4_50_10_, vehiclecla11_.id as id1_71_11_, vehiclecla11_.rec_change_date as rec_chan2_71_11_, vehiclecla11_.rec_create_date as rec_crea3_71_11_, vehiclecla11_.description as descript4_71_11_, vehiclecla11_.name as name5_71_11_, vehiclecla11_.order as order6_71_11_ from financing_price_list_mod_ver financingp0_ left outer join financing_price_list financingp1_ on financingp0_.financing_price_list_id=financingp1_.id left outer join financing_supplier financings2_ on financingp1_.financing_supplier_id=financings2_.id left outer join financing_price_list_dnpmt financingp3_ on financingp0_.financing_price_list_dnpmt_id=financingp3_.id left outer join financing_price_list financingp4_ on financingp3_.financing_price_list_id=financingp4_.id left outer join financing_price_list_millage financingp5_ on financingp0_.financing_price_list_millage_id=financingp5_.id left outer join financing_price_list financingp6_ on financingp5_.financing_price_list_id=financingp6_.id left outer join financing_price_list_periods financingp7_ on financingp0_.financing_price_list_periods_id=financingp7_.id left outer join financing_price_list financingp8_ on financingp7_.financing_price_list_id=financingp8_.id left outer join mod_ver modver9_ on financingp0_.mod_ver_id=modver9_.id left outer join mod_ver_status modverstat10_ on modver9_.status_id=modverstat10_.id left outer join vehicle_class vehiclecla11_ on modver9_.vehicle_class_id=vehiclecla11_.id where financingp0_.id=? [42001-200]
```

I think its something with the many to one mappings but any idea please ?

Answer (score 1):

`@ManyToOne` and `@OneToOne` mappings are eager by default which manifests itself in joins. If you don't want that, and believe me that probably nobody really wants that, you have to use `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`.

Since you are not sharing the error details, I can't say anything about the error.